# Проблема с записью в файл на сервере Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache

Путь файла на сервере Ubuntu14: /home/megadmin/public_html/mytestsite.com/index.php

```
<?php
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
file_put_contents("working.txt","hello world");
?>
```

проблема заключается в том, что если запустить файл с консоли сервера с правами `megaadmin`, то файл `working.txt` сохраняется в текущую папку: `/home/megadmin/public_html/mytestsite.com`, а если открыть файл через браузер, то в логах ошибок выдаёт:

`PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(working.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/megadmin/public_html/mytestsite.com/index.php on line 5`

В чём может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

наверное в том, что, пользователь под которым работает веб-сервер и пользователь под которым вы запускали команду - два разных пользователя

Comment: добавил права апача, сенкс, чё-то переработал сегодня :)